# Convert from a date to formatted datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I have dates stored in a database that seem to be encoded weird. 06-02-2012 is in the database encoded as 1338661020. I figured that out by doing:

```
$date = new DateTime('@1338661020');
echo $date->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

How would I convert 06-02-2012 back to 1338661020 in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strtotime() like this:

```
strtotime("06-02-2012")
```

strtotime() is a wonderful time function, can take just about any reasonable time format and covert it to Unix timestamp.